# Can we configure datasource connect timeout in JBoss?

Tags: jboss, datasource

Is it possible to configure a timeout to connect to a datasource?
In our case the database went down and JBoss was trying to connect for the entire time of database being out (more than 10 minutes). This caused all incoming requests to wait more than 10 minute which basically made server unavailable.
I would rather say "server error" to any request within few seconds of attempt to connect to database than have them timeout and make server unavailable for any other incoming requests.

We are using JB5 but plan is to upgrade to JB7 or WildFly soon. I haven't seen this in documentation of any JB version.

Thanks,
Nikolay

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this in your datasource config file xxx-ds.xml

There are a few different timeouts and settings, depending on which jdbc driving you use (I use postgresql), the initial connection timeout is

```
<initialTimeout>30</initialTimeout>
```

but you might also find these useful for managing reconnections...

```
<autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
<check-valid-connection-sql>select count(*) from some_table</check-valid-connection-sql>
<maxReconnects>30</maxReconnects>
```